# Bluetooth headphones never work with Dell XPS 15 9500 laptop running Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on my Dell XPS 15 9500 laptop. I have never been able to get any Bluetooth earphones to work with my laptop and I have had three or four different pairs. I have a new pair of earphones now and I think it's about time I figured out how to get it to work.

The earphones are OnePlus Buds Z2.

It appears that the earphones are connected properly:

[image]

But then if I play anything, it just comes through my laptop speakers as usual.

Comment: Please see if the provided answer works. I based my answer on my own BT that had the same sort of issue (not using HFP)

Comment: Possibly silly, but can you open your audio settings and make sure that you've selected the Bluetooth earphones as your audio playback device?

Answer (score 5):

1. Oneplus buds Z2 probably has support for Hands-Free Profile (HFP) and not Handset Profile (HSP).
2. Linux (using pulseaudio) natively support only HSP.

I believe there are 3 ways to go about this.

- Switch profile if it is set to HFP and it does support HSP (OnePlus tends to switch between profile support on Buds (some use HFP and some also use HSP). And if you can switch yourself.
- Add support for HSP to pulseaudio. You can do that with [ofono](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ofonod.8.html). Install [instructions](https://zambrovski.medium.com/using-bluetooth-headset-on-ubuntu-790ce6eecc2) are long and does need editing of some configs.
- But I would recommend to start using pipewire as this does support HSP. In the next Ubuntu release pipewire is the default and will replace pulseaudio so it is the most future proof fix. It will also already be loaded if you use 22.04 (but also uses an older method so the next instructions should help with that) Check with:

  ```
  systemctl --user status pipewire pipewire-session-manager
  ```

Using pipewire:

To start using it you do need the ppa with the newest versions and some libraries and it is advised to use the new wireplumber over the currently used media-session (the `-` in the command removes it)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream
sudo apt update

sudo apt install pipewire-audio-client-libraries libspa-0.2-bluetooth libspa-0.2-jack
sudo apt install wireplumber pipewire-media-session-
```

and remove the pulseaudio connection to bluetooth

```
sudo apt remove pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

after that enable the new wireplumber with...

```
systemctl --user --now enable wireplumber.service
```

To verify it all went well: `pactl into` That should have a line `Server Name: pulseaudio (on Pipewire {version})`

---

To revert (again: the - removes wireplumber):

```
sudo apt remove pipewire-audio-client-libraries libspa-0.2-bluetooth libspa-0.2-jack
sudo apt install wireplumber- pipewire-media-session
```

and switch the services (not sure if the 3rd one is needed):

```
systemctl --user --now enable pipewire-media-session
systemctl --user --now disable pipewire-pulse.service pipewire-pulse.socket
systemctl --user --now reenable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
```

Comment: Thank you. When I try the line `sudo apt install wireplumber pipewire-media-session-`, I get the error: `Package 'wireplumber' has no installation candidate`.

Comment: This is a good answer, but you're missing the part where you need to add the PipeWire PPA in order for it to work on Ubuntu 20.04. https://launchpad.net/~pipewire-debian/+archive/ubuntu/pipewire-upstream?field.series_filter=focal

Comment: ah my answer is using 22.04. I will update asap/

Answer (score 2):

Try using Blueman bluetooth manager and check your output in sound settings. I got my phone, my Soundcore Life A1 BT headphones as well as my DS4 controller to work with Blueman. It also has a great and simple GUI.